# Подсчет количества ячеек в строке таблицы

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как можно получить максимальное количество ячеек из всех строк таблицы как на фото? У меня проблема в том, что ячейки, которые находятся под теми что используют rowspan не считает.

Пример таблицы.

[image: таблица]

Максимальное количество ячеек в строках 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function maxCols(id){
 var e = document.getElementById(id).children[0], c = 0, r = [];
 for (var i=0; i<e.children.length;i++) {
  var ch = e.children[i].children.length;
  for (var k in r) {
   if (!r[k]) {
    r.splice(k,1);
   }else{
    ch = ch+1;
    r[k]--;
   }
  }
  for (var ii=0;ii<e.children[i].children.length;ii++) {
   if (e.children[i].children[ii].getAttribute('rowspan')) {
    r.push(Number(e.children[i].children[ii].getAttribute('rowspan'))-1);
   }
  }
  if (c < ch) {
   c = ch;
  }
 }
 return c;
}
console.log(maxCols('table'));
```

```html
<table id="table" border="1">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
      <td>е</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td rowspan="1">1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>р</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td rowspan="6">0</td>
      <td rowspan="2">1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>н</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>п</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td rowspan="4">0</td>
      <td rowspan="2">1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>с</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>л</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td rowspan="2">0</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>к</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Что то не так)
https://jsfiddle.net/6r9kutq5/

Comment: @Wepster не сразу вник) код отредактировал, всё работает

Comment: Огромное спасибо)

Comment: А можно получить значения строк с учетом ячеек с rowspan.
Например к таблице в примере чтоб получался результат:
7211
92101
t2100
11011
310101
и так далее.
Спасибо